# ASP.NET Core 3.1 change view rather than redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1

Currently, When the user don't have the permission to particular page (i.e. 403), it will redirect to Account/AccessDenied page.

Is there any way to change the requested endpoint view rather than redirecting to another endpoint, when the user unauthorized?

For example, When the user is authorized, he/she will get the requested page like this:

```
URL: https://example.com/secret
-------------------------------------------------
SiteName Page1 Page2
-------------------------------------------------

The secret page content.

-------------------------------------------------
About Contact Support
```

And when the user is unauthorized, he/she will get something like this:

```
URL: https://example.com/secret
-------------------------------------------------
SiteName Page1 Page2
-------------------------------------------------

403
Access Denied
You do not have permission to access this page.

-------------------------------------------------
About Contact Support
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display custom view based on status code, we can use the [UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#usestatuscodepageswithreexecute-1) middleware.

For more detailed information, see: [Re-execute the middleware pipeline with the StatusCodePages Middleware to create custom error pages](https://andrewlock.net/re-execute-the-middleware-pipeline-with-the-statuscodepages-middleware-to-create-custom-error-pages/)